# Command line tools in Ubuntu touch

Tags: command-line, ubuntu-touch, phone

Can I make a call in Ubuntu phone using a command line tool, without lunching any GUI app. The same question for SMS.

Answer (score 1):

Sending sms is possible via:

```
/usr/share/ofono/scripts/send-sms /ril_0 +4917432xxxxx "good evening ali" 0
```

I've managed to get calling working via ofono too, once.
But unfortunately I have neither the snippet nor the time to work it out right now. But in order to answer your question, yes definitely possible.

Keep in mind that calls/sms made or sent this way do not show up in your phones log unless you enter them manually (there's a sqlite database IIRC).

Please consider showing some more effort in your question next time.
(Like what you've tried so far and what did not work out as expected)
That way you'll probably getting a faster answer next time.